# Access form fails to pass primary key of a view (to SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access, view

Background - the setup:

1. SQL server tables (5)
2. View on the same tables, where the Address table's ID is effectively the PK of the view
3. INSTEAD OF triggers on the view for insert, update, and delete
4. The INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger checks for a record in the 4 base tables and creates it if it doesn't exist (More background: this solves an issue where an update on the view fails because not all 5 of the base tables have a record)
5. Access db with linked tables to the 5 tables and the view itself
6. Access form that displays and allows edits of the view

The issue: an edit of a record in the form fails because the Address table's ID is passed as NULL. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column..." This comes from the INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger, described above.

To solve this it seems the form must pass the Address table's PK to the view on update. Despite having the PK shown in the linked table in Access, it isn't being passed.

What's required to have an Access form pass the PK of a view to any and all updates of records from the view?

Comment: This sounds like your trigger is the problem, not Access. Posting the definition of your `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger will greatly help us help you.

Comment: Access doesn't pass the primary key column in the `SET` clause, only in the `WHERE` clause, as it should, because primary keys should generally not be updated. If your `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger doesn't handle that properly, that's your fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would adopt a design in which the child records are not required. (use left joins in your queries).

Editing related data in Access tends to suggest that each form is based on one table. If you move focus from a main form to the child form, Access automatic saves the main record.

The fact that a customer does not have invoices, or is not booked on a tour should not matter. Most designs thus suggest that child records should not have to exist, and as a result, then most query on such data will be left joins. This approach will save tons of work. I would attempt to avoid updates on sql that is multiple tables. Each form as a general rule should be directly based on a linked table. If users need to add child reocrds, then provide a UI with the correct sub-forms that allow this. The result is each form (and sub form) is only updating one table.

Comment: I did adopt the design recommended. I found using a tab control (with each tab having a subform for a single table) more straightforward than having a view with multiple base tables and triggers.